# What does a large P value mean with regards to patients lost during follow-up?

Tags: p-value

What does "P=0.45" mean in this case?

> Complete 1-year follow-up data were obtained for
>   98.1% of the patients (11 were lost to follow-up
>   in the angiography group and 8 were lost to follow-
>   up in the FFR group [P = 0.45]). ([source](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa0807611))

It looks like they mean that the p-value is 0.45, but:

1. p=0.45 is very high
2. It is very unclear what the hypothesis was

Could someone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that they're testing whether or not the rate of response in the follow-up differed between angiography and FFR group. As such, the p-value has the usual interpretation: the probability of seeing a difference in rate at least this big, given that the underlying rate is the same (the null hypothesis is true).